# Dynamically set maximum scale of horizontal pointer slide in labview?

Tags: labview

I want to make a primitive movie player in Labview. I want the user to be able to load in a movie and have a slider to select frames. As such, I want the range of the slider to go from zero to N where N is the number of frames in the movie.

How do I set the scale of the slider programmatically?

I don't see any inputs to the slider, only one output.

Here is an example of a "Horizontal Pointer Slide" bar taken from the NI Website. The slide bar is in the upper right hand corner of the image.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Right click on the slider:

```
Create -> Property Node-> Data Entry Limits -> Maximum
Create -> Property Node-> Scale -> Range -> Maximum
```

This creates property nodes you can wire up to set the maximum limit of the slider.